# key events are working in Chrome but not in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I wrote a simple function that will hide my document on a web page if a key is triggered such as PrintScreen and Windows key.

Here is the code:

```js
document.onkeydown = windowskey;
document.onkeyup = printscreenkey;


function windowskey(e) {
  switch (e.which) {
    case 91: // left windows
    case 92: // right windows
      $("#documentViewer").hide();

      break;
  }
}

function printscreenkey(e) {
  switch (e.which) {
    case 44: // print screen
      copyToClipboard();
      $("#documentViewer").show();

      break;
    case 91: // left windows
    case 92: // right windows
      $("#documentViewer").show();

      break;
  }


}
```

This functions works perfectly on Chrome browser but I tried testing it out on other browsers such as IE11 and it didn't respond or trigger any event when I pressed those keys.

I really want to make it standardized so it works the same on all the browsers.

Did I make any mistake here?

Answer (score 3):

Not all browsers support `e.which`, but it is fully supported in jQuery. In this case, however, it isn't a jquery event `document.onkeydown = windowskey;`

I suggest you use `e.keyCode` (or both)

```
var keyCode = e.which || e.keyCode; // fallback to e.keyCode
switch (keyCode) {
  case 91:
  case 92:
    // ...
    break;
  }
```

I also suggest that you use e.key (instead of e.keyCode) which makes your code more readable/understandable and it has a decent browser support IE9+: developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key

```
switch (e.key) {
  case "Down": // IE/Edge specific value
  case "ArrowDown":
    // Do something for "down arrow" key press.
    break;
```

Comment: I tested on IE, it does triggers Windows key but not the printscreen, why is that?

Comment: @Daredevil I also suggest that you use `e.key` (instead of `e.keyCode`) which makes your code more readable/understandable and it has a decent browser support IE9+: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key

Comment: @Daredevil `e.key` uses human-friendly strings to describe which key was pressed. It also takes into account modifier keys e.g. `shiftKey`, `Backspace`, `Enter`. `e.keyCode` on the other hand uses codes (numbers) e.g. `91`, `92`

Comment: so how does the new code looks like without using `e.keycode`?

Comment: But i am only interested in Printscreen and the windows key button

Comment: You can read more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key

Comment: Do I put "Printscreen" or 44?

Comment: Use "PrintScreen". Here's a helpful website to see what values to use with what properties https://keycode.info/

Comment: I know that website but it doesn't show the keycode info when I press print screen  but it only shows windows key

Comment: This works on chrome but it doesn't work on IE using `e.key`. But `e.keycode` works for IE